# check for memory leaks problems

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

when working with valgrind, it gets 2 memory leaks, that I can't understand where it's coming from..

here are the errors given by valgrind:

```
==22759== 192 bytes in 12 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
==22759==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22759==    by 0x402ABA: FigureCard::clone() (Card.cpp:139)
==22759==    by 0x403464: Deck::operator=(Deck const&) (Deck.cpp:39)
==22759==    by 0x40A8A4: Game::Game(char*) (Game.cpp:51)
==22759==    by 0x40FACC: main (reviiyot.cpp:18)
==22759==
==22759== 5,280 bytes in 330 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==22759==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22759==    by 0x4030CC: NumericCard::clone() (Card.cpp:228)
==22759==    by 0x403464: Deck::operator=(Deck const&) (Deck.cpp:39)
==22759==    by 0x40A8A4: Game::Game(char*) (Game.cpp:51)
==22759==    by 0x40FACC: main (reviiyot.cpp:18)
```

clone() in Card:

```
Card* NumericCard::  clone()
{    
        Card* c=new NumericCard(*this);
        return c;
}
```

operator= in Deck:

```
Deck& Deck:: operator=(const Deck& other)
{
    clean();
    vector <Card*> *c=new vector<Card*>;
    c->clear();
    for(int i=0;i<((int)other.getCards()->size());i++)
    {
        Card* c1=other.getCards()->at(i)->clone();
        c->push_back(c1);       
    }
    this->cards=c;
    return *this;      
}
```

FigureCard ctor:

```
FigureCard :: FigureCard(const Shape &shape,const Figure &figure):Card(shape),figure(figure){}
```

Card ctor:

```
Card::Card(Shape Pshape):shape(Pshape){}
```

NumericCard ctor:

```
NumericCard :: NumericCard(const Shape &shape,const int &number):Card(shape),number(number){}
```

DealCards- when I send the Card pointer to the player's linkedList of Card pointers:(that's why I use pointer of Card)

```
void Deck::  dealCards(vector<Player*> players){
    for(int j=0;j<((int)players.size());j++){
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){

            Card* c=this->fetchCard();
            players.at(j)->addCard(*(c));
        delete c;

        }

        players.at(j)->removeQuatro(); //check for reviiya
    }

    for(int i=0;i<((int)players.size());i++){
        players.at(i)->setInitialState();
    }
    this->initiaState=this->toString();
}
```

fetchCard:

```
    Card* Deck:: fetchCard(){//Returns the top card of the deck and remove it from the deck    
        if(cards!=NULL){
        if(!(this->cards->empty())){
            Card* temp=cards->front();
            cards->erase(cards->begin());
            return temp;

        }
        else{
            return NULL;
            }
        }
        else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

clear of linkedList:

```
    void linkedList::clear()
    {
        link* temp=first;

        while (temp != nullptr) {
            first=temp->getNext();
            temp->removeLinkToTrash();
            temp=first;
      }

    }
```

removeLinkToTrash:

```
void link :: removeLinkToTrash(){
    if(this->getPrev()!=NULL) // if it's not first link
        this->prev->next=this->next;
    if(this->getNext()!=NULL) //if its not last card
        this->next->prev=this->prev;
        clear();
}
```

clear of link:

```
  void link:: clear(){
            delete this->data;
            delete this;
    }
```

Deck destructor - if at the end, it still have Cards:

```
Deck::~Deck() {
    clean();


}

void Deck:: clean(){  
    if(cards!=NULL){
        for(int i=0;i<((int)cards->size());i++){
            delete cards->at(i);

  }
  }
    delete cards;

}
```

thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you use raw C pointer? A `unique_ptr<Card>` and then a `vector<unique_ptr<Card>>` should be better. And is a pointer necessary? Why not use a `vector<Card>`?

Comment: can you show numaric card and figure card ctor?

Comment: please show us where you're deleting these cards.

Comment: This is not real C++, more likely some C code inside C++ classes. I think you must revise the design of your code. For example, you do not need raw C pointers in a "regular" use of C++.

Comment: @Boiethios answering your first comment's final question, because whether it is apparent or not, the Op is using polymorphic objects in containers, which would slice with `std::vector<Card>`. I agree, however, with using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Card>>`.  From what little I see the OP's use of  contains with raw pointers is to "solve" the problem of passing containers by value to functions as parameters (riddled with bugs in itself).

Comment: Perhaps the cards popped out from fetchCard() are not deleted?

Comment: @WhozCraig Hum, okay, I had not that information about polymorphism at first; the OP edited his post.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest to you is to use [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). It's a memory leak safe C++ class that wraps classic C pointers. You create it with make_unique(constructor arguments), you don't have to bother with new/delete, you can get a classic C pointer from it with get() method if really required you can move the ownership of resource it contains to anotehr unique_ptr with move().